# Why can't I Assign between system.file types in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm effectively wanting to be able to do the following

```
var
  x, y : system.file;
begin
  x := y;
end;
```

but get the following message
[dcc32 Error] Unit3.pas(31): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Background:  I'm trying to modernise some old code and make it more testable, and there is a lot of `writeln` code to global `system.text` variables, which usually either outputs to the console or a file.  I'm wanting to remove these global variables to make them easier to test by creating a logger class where I pass the `system.text` variable as a parameter to its constructor.  Then replacing the `writeln('Some Message');` to `logger.log('Some Message');`, where I can replace the type of the logger.

Here is the full unit

```
UNIT TextLogger;

INTERFACE

USES
  LoggerInterface;

TYPE
  TTextLogger = CLASS(TInterfacedObject, ILogger)
  PROTECTED
    fOutPut : system.text;
    PROCEDURE Log (s : STRING);
    CONSTRUCTOR Create (const aOutPut : system.text);
  END;

IMPLEMENTATION

{ TTextLogger }

CONSTRUCTOR TTextLogger.Create (const aOutPut : system.text);
BEGIN
fOutPut := aOutPut; //compile error here
END;

PROCEDURE TTextLogger.Log (s : STRING);
BEGIN
Writeln (fOutPut, s);
END;

END.
```

Comment: If you want to modernize the application, you should abandon the ancient Pascal IO completely (that is, the `file` and `text` types).

Comment: And get rid of those ugly ALL CAPS (shouting) keywords. It hurts reading that kind of code (and yes, I know Wirth liked it too).

Comment: Why would you want to copy them anyway? Each of those refers to a file, and if there are two copies of them, and you use one of them, the other one might get out of sync and that could cause problems. Don't do that!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, I would agree with you, but that would be a huge job, I'm just doing baby steps currently by creating some abstractions that can be changed later.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis  RE: ALL CAPS - yes, try working with it all day!  (or should I say ALL DAY!!!!!) Some of the code goes back to before Turbo Pascal, so while I don't like the formatting -  it is very consistent.

Comment: You do know that the IDE has a code formatter? If the code is properly highlighted, ALL CAPS are useless.But do as @Andreas said and get rid of the old Pascal I/O.

Comment: Yes, the IDE formatter is used to make sure the code looks that way.  I usually write the code and then format it before committing.

Comment: It looks like my logger will just have to use the global variable(s).

Comment: @Alister: what do you mean? Why not use proper streaming?

Comment: "Yes, I would agree with you, but that would be a huge job" because they have repeated code everywhere? If so, I feel your pain ;-) Also, I prefer the code formatter (Ctrl-W) that comes with CnPack - does a pretty awesome job.

Comment: Getting back to your question, what does x := y even mean in this context? What I think you mean is to copy the *contents* of y to x, which, if you switch to streaming, is the assign procedure, but it could equally mean 'make x and y point to the same file'!

Comment: @DaveNottage: The code formatter of the Delphi IDE does an awesome job too, if properly set up. And it is already set up correctly to format according to the Borland/Embarcadero style guide. No need to get cnPack for that.

Comment: Imo, the problen with `x := y` would be its semantics, i.e. what does it actually **mean**?  That `x` refers to the same file in the file system as`y`, or that the contents of `y`'s file are copied to `x`'s, or what?

Comment: Probably for the same reason why you can pass file variables only as var parameters. But what is the actual constraint that prevents multiple variables pointing to the same file is unknown to me.

Answer (score 1):

Casting the System.Text variable to a TTextRec seems to allow the assignment. As some of the other commenters indicated this is probably still a bad idea and may have other side effects that are not evident in this simple test case.

```
var
  x: System.Text;
  y: System.Text;

begin
  AssignFile(x, 'c:\localdata\temp.txt');
  Rewrite(x);

  WriteLn(x, 'hello from x');

  TTextRec(y) := TTextRec(x);
  WriteLn(y, 'hello from y');

  CloseFile(y); // Both x and y are sharing the same handle, only close 1
end;
```